# How to connect to a shared folder in windows xp?

Tags: lubuntu, windows-xp, shared-folders, sharing

Alright, so I am trying to access a shared folder on Windows XP (on another computer). Both are connected to the Internet and on the same network. They run in Windows Virtual machines (that came with windows 7, can't install virtualbox). Does anyone know how to access it? Some steps or a guide would help since im pretty much a noob in lubuntu.
Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the version of *ubuntu you're using, you probably have the samba* packages already installed and required to access Windows shares. Your work however will most likely be getting the virtual machine host tools installed and working correctly on your Windows VM. Make sure firstly that your Windows share is accessible on the network (firewall, share configured correctly) and has the correct permissions. Once that is done you can try and connect to the share from your *ubuntu machine, this is a good starting point: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0

Answer (score 0):

This article may help you:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29167/3-easy-ways-to-connect-to-windows-shared-folders-from-linux/

It may need **samba** installed in your system.